# Element disappears too quickly for Jest to notice

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I am testing whether a loading spinner is displayed when data is fetching. Because the endpoint doesn't exist the response is `SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0` because of the `json()` function I am using on the awaited response.

What am I supposed to do for jest to see that the loading spinner is there? I can see it flashing for a split of a second... Can I stretch the `getOrganizationInfo` loading period somehow for the element to be visible?

The test fails with

> received value must be an HTMLElement or an SVGElement. Received has value: null

Here's my simple test

```
describe('opened Dialog', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    render(
      <DialogProvider>
        < StepByStepDialog />
      </DialogProvider>,
    );
    fireEvent.click('button', { name: 'Import Existing' }));
  };

  it('displays loading spinner on loading', async () => {
    const orgNameInput = screen.getByLabelText('Organization Name');
    fireEvent.change(orgNameInput, { target: { value: 'ABC123' } });

    fireEvent.click('button', { name: 'Continue' });
    const loading = screen.queryByText('Validating Organization...');
    expect(loading).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
});
```

My dialog component

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Dialog, DialogHeader, DialogBody, DialogFooter } from '../Dialog';
import { useDialogContext } from './DialogContext';
import { Button } from '../Button';
import { DetailsStepBody } from './DetailsStepBody';
import { DialogFooterNavigation } from '../shared/DialogFooterNavigation';
import { DialogStep } from '../shared/models';
import { getOrganizationInfo } from '../utils/organizationUtils';
import { LoadingTemplate } from '../LoadingTemplate';

export const StepByStepDialog = () => {
  const {
    step,
    isDialogOpen,
    organizationName,
    isOrganizationNameValid,
    organizationNameValidationError,
  } = useDialogContext();

  const [loadingMessage, setLoadingMessage] = useState('');

  const steps: DialogStep[] = [
    {
      name: 'Details step',
      body: <DetailsStepBody />,
      isContinueDisabled: !organizationName.value.trim(),
      onContinue: async () => {
        setLoadingMessage('Validating Organization...');

        try {
          const organizationRes = await getOrganizationInfo(organizationName.value);

          isOrganizationNameValid.setValue(organizationRes.success);

          if (organizationRes.success) {
            step.setValue(step.value + 1);
          } else {
            organizationNameValidationError.setValue(organizationRes.errorMessage);
          }
        } catch (error) {
        } finally {
          setLoadingMessage('');
        }
      },
    },
    {
      name: 'Second step',
      body: <></>,
    },
  ];

  const currentStep = steps[step.value];
  const onContinue = () =>
    currentStep.onContinue ? currentStep.onContinue() : step.setValue(step.value + 1);

  const isLoading = !!loadingMessage;

  return (
    <>
      <Button onClick={() => isDialogOpen.setValue(true)}>
        Import Existing
      </Button>

      <Dialog>
        <DialogHeader>
          <h3>Step by step dialog</h3>
        </DialogHeader>

        <DialogBody>
          {isLoading ? <LoadingTemplate msg={loadingMessage} /> : currentStep.body}
        </DialogBody>

        {isLoading ? (
          <></>
        ) : (
          <DialogFooter>
            <DialogFooterNavigation
              onContinue={onContinue}
              isContinueDisabled={!!currentStep.isContinueDisabled}
            />
          </DialogFooter>
        )}
      </Dialog>
    </>
  );
};
```

Here's my `getOrganizationInfo` function I am using to fetch the data

```
import { ErrorCodes } from './errors';

interface ResponseFailure {
  success: false;
  errorMessage: string;
}

interface OrganizationInfo {
  organization_name: string;
  deployment: string;
}

type OrganizationInfoResponse =
  | { success: true; organizationInfo: OrganizationInfo }
  | ResponseFailure;

export const getOrganizationInfo = async (
  organizationName: string,
): Promise<OrganizationInfoResponse> => {
  let organizationInfoResponse: OrganizationInfoResponse;

  try {
    const rawRes = await fetch(`/organizations/${organizationName}`);
    const res = await rawRes.json();

    if (rawRes.status >= 400) {
      if (res.errorCode === ErrorCodes.NOT_FOUND) {
        throw new Error('Organization not found');
      } else {
        throw new Error('Unable to get organization information.');
      }
    }

    organizationInfoResponse = {
      success: true,
      organizationInfo: res,
    };
  } catch (error) {
    organizationInfoResponse = {
      success: false,
      errorMessage: error.toString(),
    };
  }

  return organizationInfoResponse;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

In the same folder where your `organizationUtils.js` file is placed create `__mocks__` folder with `organizationUtils.js` file in it. In that file create mock for `getOrganizationInfo` function with `setTimeout` call in it, for example:

```
export const getOrganizationInfo = jest.fn(() => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    Promise.resolve() // here you can put mocked api response if you want
  }, 3000)
})
```

Then in your `spec`-file above all imports you should tell Jest to use mocked `organizationUtils.js` file like this:

```
jest.mock('../utils/organizationUtils') // put here the right path
```

Now the function is mocked and the spinner must be displayed for 3 seconds, but we can control timers in our test and your test will look like this:

```
it('displays loading spinner on loading', async () => {
  jest.useFakeTimers() // we are telling Jest to use fake timers
  const orgNameInput = screen.getByLabelText('Organization Name');
  fireEvent.change(orgNameInput, { target: { value: 'ABC123' } });

  fireEvent.click('button', { name: 'Continue' });
  jest.runTimersToTime(2000) // we are telling Jest to ‘jump’ to certain time we want, assuming that on 2nd second the spinner still be shown
  const loading = screen.queryByText('Validating Organization...');
  expect(loading).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

Btw, you should always mock API-calls in your tests.